# Dropping SYN attack on C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, security

I have already created a socket, and after that I have write a 'receive from':

```
sock_raw = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw, buffer, 65536, 0, &saddr, &saddr_size);
```

I have restricted this to my SYN ATTACKER package

```
printf((unsigned int)tcph->syn);
```

How can I drop that packet?

Comment: Am I missing the obvious or is the answer "You can't — it's already been received"?  I'm not completely sure about the raw socket interface.  If you can drop it, you do so by simply not responding. The `printf()` call shown is bogus (or lethal — `printf()` expects a `char *` as its first argument, not an `unsigned int`!).

Comment: That `printf` is going to bite you if the `unsigned int` gets casted to a `char *` (which it currently _is_, since you apparently aren't compiling with `-Wall -Werror`, like you should be) and that `char *` points to anything that contains a `%` followed by an invalid format specifier (which is a surprisingly high chance)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. It's too late. By the time your code gets it, the kernel is also processing the SYN (has probably finished in fact).

Defending against SYN floods is difficult and extremely technical and cannot be done with a simple drop-in user-space program. Linux has some SYN flood mitigation already built in. It is based on the SYN cookie technique (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies), and is enabled on linux with the `tcp_syncookies sysctl` parameter.

If you really want to do this yourself, you will need to develop kernel code. The existence of this question though suggests that this is well beyond your current expertise.

An alternative approach is to interpose another machine in front of the one to be defended where that other machine is receiving traffic in raw mode and can choose whether to forward packets to the protected machine. In that case, you could get away with doing this in user-space. (Obviously huge potential performance issues with this if not done with the utmost care.)

This is all assuming that you really are trying to defend against a SYN flood. If you simply wish to block SYNs from certain sources, that can be achieved out-of-the-box with the built-in linux `iptables` facility. This also depends on an in-kernel implementation that is intimately tied to the underlying network stack.